# How to create an external data source based on a Web Service?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-services, external-content-type, wcf

Can you please advise me "How to create an external data source based on a Web Service"? Usually WCF can be a data source, but I am not strong on WCF. Could I use the existing web service as an external data source?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create external data source in SharePoint Designer with *.asmx service, but Microsoft recommends not use it.
Example here: [Connect to another library in SharePoint Designer 2010](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/cizi/archive/2010/08/01/connect-to-another-library-in-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx)
and
web-service list: [SharePoint 2010 Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705814)

Answer (score 1):

You can use BCS to create external content type and provide CRUD operations through SharePoint UI.
[MSDN: How to: Create an External Content Type Based on a WCF Endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556831.aspx)

Comment: I meant: based on a web service(asmx) rather than WCF.

Comment: Writing a wrapping WCF is your best bet :)

Comment: Do you know how to publish it in IIS? I just tried a simple WCF.